# Is not having an answer publicly available a good reason to close a question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, close-reasons, off-topic

I asked [this question](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/172626/15673), which was put [on hold] with the following comment:

> I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because only the internal dev teams of these products can speak to their development roadmaps

I really do not understand the reasoning behind this. I also do not believe that the technical close reason (`off-topic`) is valid.

1. I believe the question is relevant for this site, as it relates to security practices, improvement of these practices, and how this impacts the generation of (domain-signed) certificates.
2. I don't think that a suspicion that the answer can only be given by a product team is not a valid close reason. As I said earlier in a comment, you never know who reads stackoverflow. Perhaps a member of the product team can provide an answer. Having that answer on stackoverflow is valuable for more visitors.

**Is this question valid for this site? How can I improve the question? Is the close reason given valid?**

Answer (score 13):

"When will a vendor implement a new feature?" is not a great question, even if the answer has security implications. Until the information is made public, all we can do is opine.

If there was a member of the vendor's dev staff willing to answer, they would either have to:

1. break confidentiality (not something we would want to encourage)
2. disclose something here that they would naturally want to be communicated from their own communication channels
3. link to their official communication with the answers you seek

The answer ends up being: keep checking the vendor forums.

Comment: That said, I'm happy to be overruled, but the paradigm here is clear